# Why would I set a learning rate for adaptive optimization algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Adaptive stochastic optimization algorithms like Adam, RMSProp and Adagrad are known for adaptively change the parameters in the course of learning the weights.

However, when working with such algorithms, Keras provides the option to set the learning rate. Why would you do this if a proper value is found adaptively otherwise?

Comment: See my answer to the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479007/how-to-setup-adaptive-learning-rate-in-keras/56625691#56625691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option for Adam's does not let you manually set the learning rate itself, only it's initial value. The optimizer will adjust it's learning rate accordingly.

I'm not 100% sure if the same goes for the other optimizers but i would assume so.