# How to Setup Adaptive Learning Rate in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Below is my code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(32,), activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    Dense(65, input_shape=(65,), activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(SGD(lr=.1), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=1000,shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

How will I set an adaptive learning rate of my model?

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to recompile the model as the other answer suggested. `Keras` comes with `callbacks` which can be used for this task. More precisely, you can use `LearningRateScheduler` callback and pass it some function that will adapt the learning rate based on the current epoch index.

Suppose that you want your learning rate to be some number times the epoch index (probably not the best idea but easy to comprehend)

```
def adapt_learning_rate(epoch):
    return 0.001 * epoch
```

Now that we have our function we can create a learning scheduler that is responsible for calculating the learning rate at the beginning of each epoch.

```
my_lr_scheduler = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(adapt_learning_rate)
```

Last thing to do is to pass this callback to the `fit` method.

```
model.fit(X, y, ..., callbacks=[my_lr_scheduler])
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a workaround.

For each_iteration in range(0, MaxEpoch):

1. Specify your own learning rate function that outputs a learning rate lr with respect to per epoch. The lr is then passed to your_optimiser
2. run model.compile(...optimizer=your_optimiser...)
3. run model.fit(...epochs = 1...)
4. After the ONE epoch, use model.save_weights(...)
5. Load weights by model.load_weights(...) for next iteration. See here for details https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

In fact, #4 and #5 enables you to do a transfer learning

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `SGD` here

```
model.compile(SGD(lr=.1), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with one of the provided optimizers, e.g. Adam:

```
model.compile(Adam(lr=.1), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Read this https://keras.io/optimizers/

Answer (score -1):

you can just add a decay parameter to the optimiser (although that's not exactly adaptive, it assumes that the model will indeed converge as it learns), starting with a large learning rate and decreasing it gradually as the model converges. your compiler becomes:

```
model.compile(SGD(lr=.1, decay=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Weight decay is not the same as adaptive learning rate.

Comment: I was assuming that the model converges as it learns, the rate of decay may not be the same as the rate of convergence, but the simplicity may justify the potential difference in performance.